# Can I use cursor deallocate without cursor close?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

What is proper way to close t-sql cursor? 
Is it always required to call close  before deallocate  
Can I use cursor deallocate without cursor close?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you forget to close and deallocate cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605683/what-happens-when-you-forget-to-close-and-deallocate-cursor)

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. `tsql` narrows down the software choices, but it isn't specific.